# SYS_REFCURSOR is returning all the rows from table without considering the IN parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor

I am facing a weird problem here.

```
PROCEDURE USL_EMPLOYEEBYID (  
  EMPLOYEE_ID IN NUMBER,
  EMPIDCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
OPEN EMPIDCURSOR FOR  
   SELECT emp.employee_id,emp.employee_name,emp.present_address,emp.permanent_address,emp.status 
   FROM Employee_Info emp 
   WHERE emp.employee_id = EMPLOYEE_ID;
END;
```

This procedure should give me a single employee upon entering the employee Id. But it is returning all the employees.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, Oracle interprets `EMPLOYEE_ID` as the column `EMPLOYEE_ID`, not the input parameter, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-7A77C7A5-F6BE-49F4-A398-EDD8646CE2C9) you find something more; in this way, your `where` condition is something like `a=a`.

Change the parameter name to distinguish it from the table column:

```
PROCEDURE USL_EMPLOYEEBYID (  
  p_EMPLOYEE_ID IN NUMBER,
  po_EMPIDCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
OPEN po_EMPIDCURSOR FOR  
   SELECT emp.employee_id,emp.employee_name,emp.present_address,emp.permanent_address,emp.status 
   FROM Employee_Info emp 
   WHERE emp.employee_id = p_EMPLOYEE_ID;
END;
```

this is a good practice, to always know in your code whether you are handling an input parameter, a local variable, a column and so on

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice that earlier.

Comment: @Abdullah-Al-Nahian - Another good (and common) practice is to precede all identifiers by a qualifier, to show where everything is coming from. In your code you had `emp.employee_id`, showing that this is from the `emp` table. Similarly, on the right-hand side you could have written `usl_employeebyid.employee_id`, to show explicitly that this refers to the procedure parameter, and there would be no confusion - you would get the expected result. This is neither better nor worse than what Aleksej suggested, it's just a different way to solve the same issue.